# Trying to arrange two gganimate plots throws error: Error in magick_image_info(image) : rsession.exe: Invalid geometry argument

Tags: r, rmagick, gganimate

I am trying to arrange to gganimate plots side by side. All the code executes, but when I call the resultant gif I get the following error:

```
Error in magick_image_info(image) : 
  rsession.exe: Invalid geometry argument
```

Searching for that error, I get no results on google.

I can't pull together a full reproducible example as the df's underlying the two animations are large. Below is the code that I use to try and arrange the two animations together. Note that both the individual animations run fine on their own.

```
#load libraries
library('ggplot')
library('gganimate')
library('magick')

#create the first animation
a <- ggplot(df, aes(...)) +
... #rest of ggplot call
 transition_time(year)
#create the second animation
a2 <- ggplot(df, aes(...)) +
... #rest of ggplot call
transition_reveal(year)

#Render the animations
#The value of of length(unique(df$year)) is the same across both calls
anim1 <- animate(a, nframes = length(unique(df$year)), fps = 3)
anim2 <- animate(a2, nframes = length(unique(df$year)), fps = 3)

#Convert the gifs to magick objects
anim1_magic <- image_read(anim1)
anim2_magic <- image_read(anim2)

#Combine the magick objects into a single gif
#This code completes without an error
anim1_2 <- image_append(c(anim1_magic[1], anim2_magic[1]), stack = F)
for(i in 2:length(unique(berk_records$year)) - 12) {
  combined <- image_append(c(anim1_magic[i], anim2_magic[i]))
  anim1_2 <- c(anim1_2, combined)
}

#display the combined animation
anim1_2
```

Throws error:

```
Error in magick_image_info(image) : 
  rsession.exe: Invalid geometry argument
```

I can try and `dput` some data if that would be helpful, but if anyone can see what the issue is here, that would be very much appreciated.